# How to write if inside another if in bash scripting language

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write if inside another if to be looks like :

```
if(condition)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        //do something
    }

    //do something
}
```

How to write that but in bash scripting language ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to start with a [Unix Shell Scripting Tutorial](http://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/unixscripting/unixscripting.html)?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

Comment: this will help you: [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Comment: Have a nice time with bash scripting..so amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is:

```
if [ condition ]; then
    if [ condition ]; then
    #Do something                                                                                                                                  
    elif [ condition ]; then
        #Do something                                                                                                                                  
    fi
else
    #Do something                                                                                                                                      
fi
```

You can also check conditions together with `&&`(AND) and with `||`(OR)
and many other things to know...

You can start from [HERE](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) and [HERE](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/)

Comment: @Akari I updated the answer with two useful links :)

Answer (score 3):

Condition tests using the if/then construct may be nested. The net result is equivalent to using the && compound comparison operator.

```
a=3

if [ "$a" -gt 0 ]
then
  if [ "$a" -lt 5 ]
  then
    echo "The value of \"a\" lies somewhere between 0 and 5."
  fi
fi

# Same result as:

if [ "$a" -gt 0 ] && [ "$a" -lt 5 ]
then
  echo "The value of \"a\" lies somewhere between 0 and 5."
fi
```